# Program crashes when running this function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble with wrapping my head around pointers, and using pointers in structs. To start, I don't know if I am using the pointer properly in the struct. Additionally, when I run my program, it seems to crash when it reaches readRecords, so there must be something wrong with it. Since I don't quite know how to use pointers very well, I am probably doing something wrong here... I just don't know what. Is there some way that I can edit this function so that I don't get crashes? Also, I have to keep these functions, as they are part of my project requirements.

```
struct testScores
{
    string name;
    string idNum;
    int testNum;
    int *tests;    // This is supposed to be a dynamically allocated array
    double average;
    char grade;
};

[...]

void arrStruct(testScores*& sPtr)
{
    sPtr = new testScores[];
}

void readRecords(ifstream& data, int record, testScores*& sPtr)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < record; count++)
    {
        data >> sPtr[count].name;
        data >> sPtr[count].idNum;
        data >> sPtr[count].testNum;
        sPtr[count].tests = new int[sPtr[count].testNum];   // tests is dynamically allocated (?)
        for (int tCount = 0; tCount < sPtr[count].testNum; tCount++)
            data >> sPtr[count].tests[tCount];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run your program in a debugger? WHERE does it crash?

Comment: `sPtr = new testScores[];` - how many structs are meant to be in this array? I don't know, and neither does the compiler. Accessing any memory pointed to by `sPtr` after this causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I tried using the Local Windows debugger that comes with VC2013, but I don't even know what it means. But this is what it said "Unhandled exception at 0x01318E66 in TopicH.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xABABABAB."

Comment: @etheranger Ah, that was it. I added a const int into the parameters and used that int to specify the size of the array. In the end, it wasn't even the pointers that was messing things up... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @iEclipse no worries, i've submitted that as an answer, please accept it if your problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sPtr = new testScores[];
```

This appears to be illegal syntax - array `new` requires a subscript to know how much space to allocate.
Usually this is at least 1, in your case the compiler probably interprets this as `new testScores[0]` which does return a valid pointer, but without allocating any memory from the heap.

Of course any subsequent access to memory pointed to by `sPtr` is out-of-bounds and causes undefined behaviour (in your case a crash).